# JasperReports export CSV, empty output

Tags: csv, jasper-reports, export-to-csv

Using JasperReports to export to PDF works. But when i export to CSV, i get an empty file :/

The jasper .jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Unnamed" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30"> 

<field name="id" class="java.lang.Long"/>

<detail>
    <band height="100">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="5" width="50" height="15"/>
            <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>        
    </band>
</detail>
```

The javacode:

```
JasperReport jasperReport =       JasperCompileManager.compileReport(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("template.jrxml"));

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, getDataSource());

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JRExporter exporter = new JRCsvExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
return baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: from the code you have posted it looks fine, but you do not have the code where you write it to an actual file. Are you sure that is working correctly? Is the byte[] array returned null or empty?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you call exporter.exportReport().

Answer (score 1):

yes you only need add exporter.exportReport();

after exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);

and works fine.

Comment: it says that the OUTPUT_STREAM is depricated